# Как повернуть svg элемент на 90 градусов

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation

как сделать анимацию поворота на 90 градусов svg элемента? На [данном сайте](http://www.singmovie.com/) если открыть на мобильном и повернуть экран в landscape появляется иконка поверните экран, она в svg. Как добиться такого же эффекта? Не селен в svg((

```css
.rotate {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #000;
}
.rotate-icon {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 127px;
    height: 135px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -67.5px 0 0 -63.5px;
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
  <svg class="rotate-icon" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 127 134.1" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">.rotate0{fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.rotate1{fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.rotate2{fill: #fff; stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style>
    <g data-svg-origin="63.45000076293945 67.00000381469727">
      <path class="rotate0" d="M65.5,45.4h31.3c4.3,0,7.8,3.5,7.8,7.8v27.6c0,4.3-3.5,7.8-7.8,7.8H30.1c-4.3,0-7.8-3.5-7.8-7.8V53.2
                               c0-4.3,3.5-7.8,7.8-7.8h12.4H65.5z"></path>
      <line class="rotate1" x1="27.9" y1="70.2" x2="27.9" y2="63.9"></line>
    </g>
    <path class="rotate0" d="M125.5,67c0-34.2-27.8-62-62-62"></path>
    <path class="rotate0" d="M1.5,67c0,34.2,27.8,62,62,62"></path>
    <polygon class="rotate2" points="63.5,1.2 59.7,5 63.5,8.9 "></polygon>
    <polygon class="rotate2" points="63.5,132.9 67.3,129 63.5,125.2 "></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: А чем `transform: rotate` не подходит?

Comment: когда делаю transform: rotate то поворачивает не по центру

Comment: О, нашел, чтоб нормально по центру поварачивало, нужно тегу g прописать стиль  transform-origin: center center ))))

Comment: @Karalahti А можете переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы не надо было лазить по сторонним сайтам, чтобы понять ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используем transform для поворота

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Чтобы поварачивало по центру, нужно тегу `g` прописать стиль:

```
transform-origin: center center
```

```css
.rotate {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #000;
}
.rotate-icon {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 127px;
  height: 135px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -67.5px 0 0 -63.5px;
  stroke: #fff;
}
.rotate-icon g {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.rotate-icon:hover g {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
  <svg class="rotate-icon" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 127 134.1" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .rotate0 {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 3;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
      .rotate1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 3;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
      .rotate2 {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
    </style>
    <g data-svg-origin="63.45000076293945 67.00000381469727">
      <path class="rotate0" d="M65.5,45.4h31.3c4.3,0,7.8,3.5,7.8,7.8v27.6c0,4.3-3.5,7.8-7.8,7.8H30.1c-4.3,0-7.8-3.5-7.8-7.8V53.2
                               c0-4.3,3.5-7.8,7.8-7.8h12.4H65.5z"></path>
      <line class="rotate1" x1="27.9" y1="70.2" x2="27.9" y2="63.9"></line>
    </g>
    <path class="rotate0" d="M125.5,67c0-34.2-27.8-62-62-62"></path>
    <path class="rotate0" d="M1.5,67c0,34.2,27.8,62,62,62"></path>
    <polygon class="rotate2" points="63.5,1.2 59.7,5 63.5,8.9 "></polygon>
    <polygon class="rotate2" points="63.5,132.9 67.3,129 63.5,125.2 "></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: А без чтения комментариев ответить слабо?)

Comment: И вообще вопрос был не по этой теме

Comment: Ну так исправьте, это же **общий** ответ

Comment: Да, все верно, так и надо было, все работает

Comment: var polygon1=canvas.append("polygon") как этот объект повернуть на 90 градусов по центру (100, 100)